# Compatibility issue between the MySQL workbench and MySQL GUI tools

Tags: mysql, compatibility, mysql-workbench, mysql-gui-tools

I've used MySQL workbench 5.0.30 OSS for creating a visual design of my database with the entities and relationships between tables.I exported the SQL create script from it.

I'm using the SQL GUI tools 5.0 r17 on windows 7 (32-bit) machine to restore the database and I see a couple of tables missing.It throws a 150 error table cant be created.

I don't understand if its the compatibility issue or is it something wrong with the err diagram.

It would be great if someone can help.The following is the SQL script.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb`;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Question_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_type` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_type` (
  `idQuestion_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Question_type_description` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Part_Marks` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Minimum_Marks` INT NULL ,
  `Maximum_Marks` INT NULL ,
  `Close_ended` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQuestion_type`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'The type of the question';    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Question`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Question` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Question` (
  `idQuestion` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQuestion_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQuestion`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Question_type`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion_type` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question_type` (`idQuestion_type` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'The main questionID table that links to everyother';

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Question_type` ON `mydb`.`Question` (`idQuestion_type` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Answer_form`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Answer_form` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Answer_form` (
  `idAnswer_form` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `Form_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Form_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAnswer_form`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Question_form`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_form` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_form` (
  `idQuestion_form` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `Form_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Form_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQuestion_form`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`QShort_Answer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`QShort_Answer` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`QShort_Answer` (
  `idQShort_Answer` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQuestion` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQuestion_form` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Question_content` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Upload_content` LONGBLOB NULL ,
  `One_word_answer` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `One_answer1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `One_answer2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `idAnswer_form` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key3` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key4` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key5` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key6` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `No_of_words` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQShort_Answer`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QShort_Answer_Answer_form`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idAnswer_form` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Answer_form` (`idAnswer_form` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QShort_Answer_Question_form`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion_form` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question_form` (`idQuestion_form` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QShort_Answer_Question`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question` (`idQuestion` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'The short answer question table';

CREATE INDEX `fk_QShort_Answer_Answer_form` ON `mydb`.`QShort_Answer` (`idAnswer_form` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QShort_Answer_Question_form` ON `mydb`.`QShort_Answer` (`idQuestion_form` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QShort_Answer_Question` ON `mydb`.`QShort_Answer` (`idQuestion` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`QLong_Answer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`QLong_Answer` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`QLong_Answer` (
  `idQLong_Answer` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQuestion` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQuestion_form` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Question_content` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Upload_content` LONGBLOB NULL ,
  `idAnswer_form` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key3` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key4` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key5` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Answer_key6` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `No_of_words` INT NULL ,
  `Rubric_used` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQLong_Answer`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QLong_Answer_Question_form`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion_form` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question_form` (`idQuestion_form` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QLong_Answer_Answer_form`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idAnswer_form` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Answer_form` (`idAnswer_form` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QLong_Answer_Question`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question` (`idQuestion` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QLong_Answer_Question_form` ON `mydb`.`QLong_Answer` (`idQuestion_form` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QLong_Answer_Answer_form` ON `mydb`.`QLong_Answer` (`idAnswer_form` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QLong_Answer_Question` ON `mydb`.`QLong_Answer` (`idQuestion` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Multichoice_question`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Multichoice_question` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Multichoice_question` (
  `idMultichoice_question` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQuestion` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQuestion_form` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Question_content` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Upload_content` LONGBLOB NULL ,
  `Option1` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Option2` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Option3` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Option4` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Option5` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Option6` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMultichoice_question`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Multichoice_question_Question_form`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion_form` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question_form` (`idQuestion_form` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Multichoice_question_Question`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question` (`idQuestion` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Multiple choice Questions';

CREATE INDEX `fk_Multichoice_question_Question_form` ON `mydb`.`Multichoice_question` (`idQuestion_form` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Multichoice_question_Question` ON `mydb`.`Multichoice_question` (`idQuestion` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`QCalculated`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`QCalculated` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`QCalculated` (
  `idQCalculated` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQuestion` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQuestion_form` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Question_content` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Upload_content` LONGBLOB NULL ,
  `Number_of_wildcards` INT NULL ,
  `Wildcard1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Wvalue1` INT NULL ,
  `Wmax1` INT NULL ,
  `Wmin1` INT NULL ,
  `Wdecimal1` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Wildcard2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Wvalue2` INT NULL ,
  `Wmax2` INT NULL ,
  `Wmin2` INT NULL ,
  `Wdecimal2` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Wildcard3` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Wvalue3` INT NULL ,
  `Wmax3` INT NULL ,
  `Wmin3` INT NULL ,
  `Wdecimal3` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Wildcard4` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Wvalue4` INT NULL ,
  `Wmax4` INT NULL ,
  `Wmin4` INT NULL ,
  `Wdecimal4` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Wildcard5` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Wvalue5` INT NULL ,
  `Wmax5` INT NULL ,
  `Wmin5` INT NULL ,
  `Wdecimal5` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Wildcard6` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Wvalue6` INT NULL ,
  `Wmax6` INT NULL ,
  `Wmin6` INT NULL ,
  `Wdecimal6` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Wildcard7` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Wvalue7` INT NULL ,
  `Wmax7` INT NULL ,
  `Wmin7` INT NULL ,
  `Wdecimal7` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Formula` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Formula_unit1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Formula_unit2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Formula_unit3` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Formula_unit4` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Formula_unit5` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Tolerance` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQCalculated`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QCalculated_Question_form`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion_form` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question_form` (`idQuestion_form` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QCalculated_Question`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question` (`idQuestion` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Generalized calculation type question';

CREATE INDEX `fk_QCalculated_Question_form` ON `mydb`.`QCalculated` (`idQuestion_form` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QCalculated_Question` ON `mydb`.`QCalculated` (`idQuestion` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Board`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Board` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Board` (
  `idBoard` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `Board_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Board_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Class` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Year` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBoard`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Class_subject_term`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Class_subject_term` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Class_subject_term` (
  `idCST` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idBoard` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Class_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Class_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Subject_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Subject_shortname` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Subject_group` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCST`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Class_subject_term_Board`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBoard` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Board` (`idBoard` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Class_subject_term_Board` ON `mydb`.`Class_subject_term` (`idBoard` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Educational_objectives`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Educational_objectives` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Educational_objectives` (
  `idEO` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `EO_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `EO_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEO`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Chapter_topic`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Chapter_topic` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Chapter_topic` (
  `idChaptop` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idCST` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Chapter_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Chapter_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Chapter_group` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idTopic` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Topic_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Term_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `idEO` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idChaptop`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Chapter_topic_Educational_objectives`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idEO` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Educational_objectives` (`idEO` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Chapter_topic_Class_subject_term`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCST` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Class_subject_term` (`idCST` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Chapter_topic_Educational_objectives` ON `mydb`.`Chapter_topic` (`idEO` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Chapter_topic_Class_subject_term` ON `mydb`.`Chapter_topic` (`idCST` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Topic_concept`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Topic_concept` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Topic_concept` (
  `idTopcon` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idTopic` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Concept_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Concept_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTopcon`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Topic_concept_Chapter_topic`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idTopic` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Chapter_topic` (`idTopic` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Topic_concept_Chapter_topic` ON `mydb`.`Topic_concept` (`idTopic` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Question_properties`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_properties` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_properties` (
  `idQuestion_properties` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQuestion` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idBoard` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Board_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `idCST` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Class_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `idChapTop` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Chapter_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `idTopcon` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Marks` INT NULL ,
  `Negative Marks` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `Repeat` BIGINT NULL ,
  `From_textbook` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  `FA_only` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQuestion_properties`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_properties_Board`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idBoard` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Board` (`idBoard` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_properties_Class_subject_term`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCST` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Class_subject_term` (`idCST` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_properties_Chapter_topic`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idChapTop` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Chapter_topic` (`idChaptop` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_properties_Topic_concept`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idTopcon` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Topic_concept` (`idTopcon` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_properties_Question`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question` (`idQuestion` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Properties of the Question';

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_properties_Board` ON `mydb`.`Question_properties` (`idBoard` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_properties_Class_subject_term` ON `mydb`.`Question_properties` (`idCST` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_properties_Chapter_topic` ON `mydb`.`Question_properties` (`idChapTop` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_properties_Topic_concept` ON `mydb`.`Question_properties` (`idTopcon` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_properties_Question` ON `mydb`.`Question_properties` (`idQuestion` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Rubric`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Rubric` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Rubric` (
  `idRubdim` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `Rubric_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Rubric_dimension` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Rubric_dimension_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Scale1_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale1_detail_description` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Scale2_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale2_detail_description` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale3` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Scale3_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale3_detail_description` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale4` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Scale4_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Scale4_detail_description` LONGTEXT NULL ,
  `Rubric_category` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Group_rubric` BOOLEAN NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRubdim`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Question_Rubric`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (
  `idRubric` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage1` INT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage2` INT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim3` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage3` INT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim4` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage4` INT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim5` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage5` INT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim6` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage6` INT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim7` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage7` INT NULL ,
  `idQRubdim8` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `QRWeightage8` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRubric`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim1` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim2` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim3` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim4` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim5` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim6` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric6`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim7` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric7`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQRubdim8` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Rubric` (`idRubdim` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim1` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric1` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim2` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric2` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim3` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric3` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim4` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric4` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim5` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric5` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim6` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric6` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim7` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Question_Rubric_Rubric7` ON `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idQRubdim8` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Learning_objectives`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Learning_objectives` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Learning_objectives` (
  `idLO` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `LO_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `LO_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `idCS` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `CS_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `CS_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLO`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`QDifficulty`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`QDifficulty` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`QDifficulty` (
  `idQDifficulty` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `Difficulty_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQDifficulty`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`QNR_Tags`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (
  `idQNR_Tags` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `idQuestion` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idRubric1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idRubric2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQCS1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQLO1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQCS2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQLO2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQDifficulty` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idQuestion_form` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idComment_set1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idComment_set2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idQNR_Tags`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_Question_Rubric`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idRubric1` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idRubric` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_Question_Rubric1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idRubric2` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question_Rubric` (`idRubric` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQLO1` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Learning_objectives` (`idLO` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQLO2` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Learning_objectives` (`idLO` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQCS1` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Learning_objectives` (`idCS` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQCS2` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Learning_objectives` (`idCS` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_QDifficulty`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQDifficulty` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`QDifficulty` (`idQDifficulty` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_QNR_Tags_Question`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestion` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Question` (`idQuestion` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_Question_Rubric` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idRubric1` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_Question_Rubric1` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idRubric2` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idQLO1` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives2` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idQLO2` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives1` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idQCS1` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_Learning_objectives3` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idQCS2` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_QDifficulty` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idQDifficulty` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_QNR_Tags_Question` ON `mydb`.`QNR_Tags` (`idQuestion` ASC) ;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Comments` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Comments` (
  `idComment` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `Comment_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `Comment_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idComment`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Comment_set`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Comment_set` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Comment_set` (
  `idComment_set` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `Comment_set_shortname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Comment_set_description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL ,
  `idComment1` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idComment2` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idComment3` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idComment4` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idComment5` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `idComment6` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idComment_set`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Comment_set_Comments`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idComment1` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Comments` (`idComment` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Comment_set_Comments1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idComment2` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Comments` (`idComment` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Comment_set_Comments2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idComment3` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Comments` (`idComment` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Comment_set_Comments3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idComment4` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Comments` (`idComment` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Comment_set_Comments4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idComment5` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Comments` (`idComment` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Comment_set_Comments5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idComment6` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Comments` (`idComment` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Comment_set_Comments` ON `mydb`.`Comment_set` (`idComment1` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Comment_set_Comments1` ON `mydb`.`Comment_set` (`idComment2` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Comment_set_Comments2` ON `mydb`.`Comment_set` (`idComment3` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Comment_set_Comments3` ON `mydb`.`Comment_set` (`idComment4` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Comment_set_Comments4` ON `mydb`.`Comment_set` (`idComment5` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Comment_set_Comments5` ON `mydb`.`Comment_set` (`idComment6` ASC) ;   

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Protip: Try to pare your pasted code to the minimum in order to describe or duplicate your issue.  Dumping all your code into a question is more likely to scare off potential help.  Also, the act of cutting down your code can sometimes help you determine what the actual problem is. I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please use MySQL Workbench 5.2 (5.0 is very old):
http://forums.mysql.com/index.php?151